# What is the theory if black goes 4 Nxc4 in evan's gambit?

Tags: opening, theory, evans-gambit

Ive been learning the theory for this opening but cant find anything if black chooses this line.

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean 4...Nxb4.

White will play 5.c3, and there is probably nothing better than 5...Nc6; so it boils down to being the same as 4...Bxb4 5.c3 **Bc5**.

```
[FEN ""]

1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bc4 Bc5 4.b4 Nxb4 5.c3 Nc6
```

Comment: In case of Nxb4, white also has the option to simply 0-0 and ignore the knight, since e5 is hanging. It's not good for white to castle when Bxb4, because of this missing threat.